# Auto add space when write file java

Tags: java, netbeans, io, filewriter, writefile

I have a function to write some data to a file.

```
{ 
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("E:\\Code\\ParseTool\\src\\ketqua.txt"), "Unicode"));

    System.out.print("{\"q\":\"" + ques + "\",\"a\":\"" + ans + "\"},");

    out.write("{\"q\":\"" + ques + "\",\"a\":\"" + ans + "\"},\n"); 
}
```

When i write to console: the data look correct:

`{"q":" ��Which of the following methods is defined by the JSP engi....`

[image]

But when the data which is writen in the txt file is auto add space character

`{"q":" ��W h i c h   o f   t h e   f o l l o w i n g   m e t h o d s   i s   d e f i n e d   b y   t h e   J S P   e n g i n e ? ","a":" A n s w e r :`

[image]

Someone help...

Comment: You are trying to view your Unicode output with a 8 bit viewer. It is treating each utf-16 2 byte character as 2 one byte characters.

Comment: Convert string to char, remove the space from char 'Character.isWhitespace(char)'

Comment: @Dragonthoughts even when i tried to replace unicode by UTF-8. The result still the same.

Comment: Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("E:\\Code\\ParseTool\\src\\ketqua.txt"), "UTF-8"));